maven-war-plugin : unable to load the mojo
I am running java version "21.0.4" 2024-07-16 LTS
I downloaded the https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/glassfish-samples. and trying to buld the jakarta9 files.
I get Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-war of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:3.0.0:war failed: Unable to load the mojo 'war' in the plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:3.0.0' due to an API incompatibility: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: null
my pom file is:
<build>
    <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Updated plugin versions -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version> <!-- Use a more recent version -->
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version> <!-- Use a more recent version -->
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version> <!-- Use a more recent version -->
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.0</version> <!-- Use a more recent version -->
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.0</version> <!-- Use a more recent version -->
            </plugin>
            <!-- Other plugins with updated versions -->
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <container>
                    <containerId>${integration.container.id}</containerId>
                    <type>installed</type>
                    <home>${glassfish.home}</home>
                </container>
                <configuration>
                    <type>standalone</type>
                    <home>${glassfish.home}/glassfish/domains</home>
                </configuration>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M2</version> <!-- Update to a newer version -->
            <configuration>
                <mavenExecutorId>forked-path</mavenExecutorId>
                <useReleaseProfile>false</useReleaseProfile>
                <arguments>${release.arguments}</arguments>
                <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
                <tagNameFormat>@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-gitexe</artifactId>
                    <version>1.11.2</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


Any suggestion??
I tried the maven-compiler-plugin, maven-war-plugin to be as most compatible wth java 21.

This explains why it doesn't work: What is pluginManagement in Maven's pom.xml?. You need to put maven-war-plugin in  instead. The  only represents the default config for whatever is declared multiple times in . If you don't use explicitly declare maven-war-plugin in the  then the default one (supplied by Maven installation) will be used. The alternative is of course to upgrade your Maven installation.

It is required to have the appropriate <packaging>war</packaging> which is given because otherwise the plugins wouldn't even being executed. Furthermore which Maven version do you use? Also if the error still persist build the project on plain command line...
